# Создание транзакций в Spring внутри одного bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transaction

Есть сущность который отмечена как bean и в ней есть два public метода.
Оба метода помещены аннотацией @transactional.

```
@Component
public class Main{
@transactional
public void one(){
 //вызывает метод two()
}

@transactional
public void two(){}
}
```

мне интересно будет создано 2 транзакции или все таки одна? Ведь вызов происходит внутри одного метода и общего бина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы говорим про аннотацию `javax.transaction.Transactional`, то в состоянии "по-умолчанию", будет создана одна транзакция. Аннотация принимает в качестве аргумента так называемый `TxType`. Это такой enum, которым внутри контекста разруливается поведение транзакции. По-умолчанию выставлено значение `TxType.REQUIRED`, которое означает, что при выполнении метода требуется сессия, для выполнения транзакции. Если такой сессии внутри контекста нет -она будет создана (в вашем случае в момент вызова метода `one`), если же сессия уже есть в контексте (вызов метода `two`), то текущая транзакция будет продолжена.

Comment: спасибо. почитал про TxType стало ясней.